# Is there a way to trigger the particular endpoint in Cloud run job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jobs, google-cloud-run

I deployed a Springboot app in Cloud run Jobs and i want to trigger a particular endpoint of that application

Is there a way to trigger the particular endpoint in Cloud run job ?

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Link1](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Cloud-run-job-trigger-when-another-job-completes/td-p/618444) and [Link2](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudRunner/reference/cr_run_schedule_http.html).

Comment: Cloud Run jobs does not expose any endpoints. only the Cloud Run Jobs service endpoint, be no container (your code) endpoint. Use standard Cloud Run for that. If you want to change the parameters and the argument of your Cloud Run Jobs, you can have a look on the brand new feature "parameter override".

Comment: It was deployed in Cloud run previosuly, issue is that a particular endpoint(@Scheduled) runs for more than 1 hour which is not supported in Cloud run. That is why we switched to Cloud run Jobs which can run upto 24hours. Now we are stuck with triggering that endpoint.

Comment: As @guillaume blaquiere, suggested in the above comment and as per this [Article](https://medium.com/@hello_9187/making-a-serverless-http-endpoint-for-cloud-run-jobs-5e581412e5e1#:~:text=Importantly%2C%20Cloud%20Run%20jobs%20do,supporting%20long%2Drunning%20containerized%20tasks) cloud run job does not trigger endpoints.

Comment: As an alternative you can check the suggestions stated in this [Medium](https://medium.com/@hello_9187/making-a-serverless-http-endpoint-for-cloud-run-jobs-5e581412e5e1#:~:text=custom%20parameterization%20requirements.-,The%20Solution,-We%20can%20create) like using gcloud commands, the Cloud Run jobs API, or Cloud Scheduler. Also have a look at this [Link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Cloud-Run-container-time-limitaion/m-p/535775).

Comment: Cloud Run Jobs is a batch environment: it runs a container until completion. Create your container, invoke it with the appropriate parameters (parameter override) and that's all. It's not a webservice, it's a batch.

Comment: Have you tried writing the code to trigger a batch? Have you succeeded or facing any issues?

Comment: I made my application as a batch and deployed in Cloud run jobs. Cloud Scheduler to trigger the application. There is no way to call the particular endpoint in Cloud run Jobs since it runs the app only as batch.